# COUNT cells, skip empty and with formula that results to ""

Tags: excel-formula

I have formulas in range `H13:O13` that are giving `=""` as a result. For example `=IF(A1="";"";A1)` in `B1`. I would like to count number of values that are not `=""`.

Some cells are merged in `H13:O13`.

I have tried:

```
=COUNTIF(H13:O13;"")
```

COUNTIF works but back wise. It is like amount of cells - used ones

also

```
=COUNT(H13:O13)
```

COUNT does not recognize `=""`. If cell result is `=""` it counts it as well.

---

**EDIT:**

Suggested formula:

```
=COUNT(H13:O13)-COUNTIF(H13:O13;"")
```

[image]

Result is -2, it should be 3 as there are 3 values in range and one is empty. I know they are merged but that is what I am expecting from formula

Comment: and what happened when you tried those, and why was that wrong?

Comment: `COUNTA` counts used cells, but it will count cells that return `""`. `COUNTIF(B1:B50;"<>")` does the same. But `COUNTIF(B1:B50;"")` correctly counts empties, so your best bet is `COUNT(B1:B50) - COUNTIF(B1:B50;"")`.

Comment: Well I would like to know amount of used cells. This formula is giving me -8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ROWS(B1:B50)-COUNTIF(B1:B50,"")
```

it will not count empty cells or cells containing stuff like `=""`

**TRICK:**

If you have a block of cells like **A1** through **E5**, then:

```
=ROWS(A1:E3)*COLUMNS(A1:E3)-COUNTIF(A1:E3,"")
```

[image]

Comment: `=COLUMNS(H13:O13)-COUNTIF(H13:O13;"")`seems to be the answer according to picture with example attached

Comment: @user7202022  I am using the range in the top of your question.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I have mistaken in my question. My values are in horizontal way...